# Xamarin.iOS App with push notifications: invalid provisioning profile during delopment

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a Xamarin.iOS app, and I cannot test it on my iPhone due to the following error:

> Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured.
>   Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current
>   provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current
>   provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details
>   (error: 0xe8008016).

The same app compiles fine in release mode and I'm able to upload it to app store.

Custom entitlements - debug build (Entitlements.sviluppo.plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I remove custom entitlements file everyting works fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.7 Preview 1 (but I've also tried with 16.6) and xcode 11.5.

### UPDATE

I tried to completely remove and reinstall certificates (both for signing and for notifications) and provisioning profiles. I did this on mac and pc.
I also cleaned my solution and deleted bin and obj.

Using ProvisionQL I extracted info about my development provisioning profile, I add a picture of this, too.

I attach some pictures of the various settings.

### App settings

[image]

### Devices

[image: Devices]

### Provisioning profile

[image: Provisioning profile]

### Downloaded development provisioning profile

[image]

### Project settings

[image: Project settings]

### Profiles on device

[image: profiles on device]

Comment: Check that the iPhone is added to your Apple provisioning.

Also download the provisioning certificate to the Mac you are working on.

Clear the `obj` and `bin`  folders of all files, clean all and then rebuilt all.

Comment: How can I check that the iPhone is added to my Apple provisioning? I can see it in "Certificates, Identifiers and profiles" (see "Devices" image in my post).

Comment: You could try auto provisioning.

Comment: I use manual provisioning to provide custom entitlements file. I updated my question with some other info.

Comment: You could post the problem to : Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a peoblem .